# Opposite of a Heisenbug, segmentation fault that appear ONLY when debugging, but program works fine

Tags: c, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind

I've a written a simple C program with two data structures implemented as ADT, so I dynamically allocate the memory for them

Everything was working fine, until I've decided to add a int value inside a struct, nothing dynamically allocated, classic plain old simple static memory allocation, but since I've added it I've started having a segfault in a pretty safe function that shouldn't segfault at all.

I've thought about a memory allocation error, so I've tried to not free and reuse a pointer variable I was using, but instead use another variable, and doing so the program went fine.
Pissed off by all the times I had to deal with this kind of errors, I've re-enabled that free I was talking before, recompiled and made a run with valgrind.

To my surprise, there was absolutely no memory leak, no segmentation fault, not any kind of interruption, just a warn about `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`, but that's a wanted behavior (`if (pointer == NULL) { }`) so I've run the executable directly from command line and again, everything went fine, so the situation it's this:

#### Program without the new int value in the struct:

- Compile : check
- Runs : check
- Valgrind analisys: No memory leakage, just the warn
- Debug (gdb) : check

#### Program with the new int value in the struct:

- Compile : check
- Runs : check
- Valgrind analisys: No memory leakage, just the warn
- Debug (gdb) : Segfault

So I think that's the opposite of a Heisenbug, a bug that shows itself only and absolutely only when debugging, how can I try to fix this?

Comment: That is a typical sympton of *undefined behaviour*, possibly somewhere else in the program. But you should absolutely and definitely fix **all** compiler warnings such as *Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)*. It might result in "wanted behaviour" sometimes, but that's just unlucky.

Comment: Could possibly be an uninitialized pointer used without checking for null? The debugger could set the memory to zero, making the pointer equal to a null pointer. When you dereference the pointer you do a null-pointer access and the program crashes. When not running in the debugger, the pointer have an indeterminate value and in your case it just happens to contain a value that is a pointer to memory that could be read from or written to. Better check all uninitialized variables in your code.

Comment: Try different optimization flags, different `-f` options... compile with different compiler...

Comment: Consider yourself lucky and use the debugger. The place where the segfault occurs should give you some hints.

Comment: Please show more code. Comparing an uninitialized pointer with `NULL` is undefined behavior. Please explain why this is "wanted behavior"?

Comment: Oh my god thanks!, I've rechecked that variable that valgrind was complaining about, I was sure that it were initialized as `NULL`, but that wasn't the case, so it were effectively uninitialized and that caused the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK thanks to @weather-vane and @some-programmer-dude I've noticed that effectively I wasn't initializing the variable valgrind was complaining about, and I've misunderstood the valgrind warn, I was reading it as `You should not use a if to check if variables are NULL`

Comment: You appear to have your Valgrind priorities backwards: memory leaks (if any) are the *least* important, to be fixed *after* you have fixed all warnings.